# C++, использование char для доступа к элементам массива

Tags: c++, char, signed, unsigned

Я хочу уточнить один момент, касающийся использования `char` для доступа к элементам массива.

Мне известно, что `char` - это тип, единственное предназначение которого - хранить однобайтовые символы. Этот тип может быть как `unsigned char`, так и `signed char`.

Следовательно, `char` не годится для адресаций элементов массивов.

Например:

```
void Object::set(const char _char)
{
    // size_t elements[UINT8_MAX];
    elements[_char] += 1;
}
```

То есть, если `char` окажется знаковым, то мы будем писать в элементы массива с индексами [-128; 127]. Очевидно, что в массиве не существует элементов с индексами [-128; -1].

Все верно?

Или, может быть, при использовании `char` в качестве *индексомера* существует неявная конвертация в беззнаковый тип? Я сомневаюсь, что существует, но и полной уверенности, что использовать `char` в описанной ситуации нельзя, у меня нет.

Comment: В принципе, можно применять отрицательные номера элементов, если поставить начальный указатель не в начало, а в центр массива. Или в конец массива.

Comment: Лучше использовать явный `unsigned` (или `signed`) `char`.

Answer (score 2):

> char - это тип, единственное предназначение которого - хранить однобайтовые символы

Нет, это целочисленный тип, который также может хранить куски многобайтовых символов и вообще произвольные данные.

> Этот тип может быть как unsigned char, так и signed char.

Нет, это отдельный тип, хотя он может быть со знаком или без.

```
static_assert(not ::std::is_same_v<char, unsigned char>); // ok
static_assert(not ::std::is_same_v<char, signed char>); // ok
```

> char не годится для адресаций элементов массивов

Нет, он вполне годится для индексации массивов и адресной арифметики вообще если проверять предположения по поводу его знаковости и выхода за пределы.

```
void Object::set(const char index)
{
    static_assert(::std::is_unsigned_v<decltype(index)>);
    static_assert(::std::numeric_limits<decltype(index)>::max() <= ::std::size(elements));
    // size_t elements[UINT8_MAX];
    elements[index] += 1;
}
```

Comment: а не лучше обеспечить строгую безопасность. if constexpr ( index >= 0 && index < std::size(elements)) ... ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Такая проверка вообще не сработает, так как index не является константным выражением.

Comment: в данном случаи да, вы правы.  Но смысль остается _ выполнять, если...

Answer (score 1):

В качестве индекса массива в c++ кошерно использовать любой интегральный тип, то есть: `bool, char, signed char, unsigned char, char8_t, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long long`, как всегда таких случаях в Плюсах, ответственность за членовредительство лежит на программисте, никаких явных преобразований язык не проводит, поэтому в данной функции можно вставить проверку, что-то вроде `assert(_char >= 0)`